# Windows 2008 share times out when accessed from Linux clients after 10 minutes following WannaCry patches and updates

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-server-2008, samba, network-share

**A bit of background**

- We have a Windows 2008 server that users use to store all kinds of data.
- It has smb share  to a specific folder, that needs to be accessed by several Ubunutu servers via cifs.
- It worked all great until recently we had to patch Windows server against WannaCry attack.
- Also updated Ubuntu servers ( running Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS)
- Except for updates nothing changed - all the configuration is the same, and worked great for several years.
- No changes on the network

**Problem:**

Now samba share on Windows 2008 server  times out after a few minutes ( about 10), if clients don't access it. (Normally it it happens once every  few hours, when either an import or an export needs to be pulled from share or saved to it). To be clear - the share mounts on Ubuntu clients and works as expected, it just times out after a few minutes if no process uses that connection.

**Temporary solution:** we setup cron tasks, that touch a file on the windows share every 5 minutes to keep connection alive) .  - THIS DOESN"T HELP

Ended up setting up a cron task with a sudo user running `mount -a` every 5 minutes.

I would like to find out a reason for this and come up with a long term solution.

**EDIT:**

Per comments:

My mount command in /etc/fstab ( replaced sensitive info with caps)

```
//SERVER.HOST.NAME/apidata /var/www/pai3/shared/data/production/k_drive/data cifs username=USER,password=PASS,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,workgroup=DOMAIN.COM,rw,uid=1000   0  0
```

Comment: Some questions: 1) how do you mount the share? Can you provide the complete command line? 2) When the share disconnects, what do you see in dmesg? 3) Any insight on the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: @shodanshok Thanks for the reply. 1) It's a standard fstab entry / mount command 2) Where is dmesg is saved for this? 3)Nothing in the even viewer.

Comment: @shodanshok Here is fstab command ( removed sensitive info) .   will update question to keep formating

Comment: in dmesg, you should search for entries with 'smb' or 'cifs' words. For example `dmesg | grep "smb\|cifs"` You can also search in /var/log/messages or /var/log/kernel.log

Comment: @shodanshok `[   14.122342] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[   14.122486] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[   14.122500] Key type cifs.idmap registered`

Comment: that's all i got from the grep command you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [CIFS and SMB Timeout in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2013/03/19/cifs-and-smb-timeouts-in-windows/)

> **Idle Connection Timer**
>
> This is the amount of time that a connection can be idle before being
>   disconnected. An idle connection is defined as a connection which has
>   no existing open handles (no open files, directories, search contexts,
>   etc.), and no pending operation. The Idle Connection Timer is
>   implementation-specific.  When the server receives a message,
>   Server.Connection.IdleTime is set to the current time plus
>   Server.AutoDisconnectTimeout [MS-CIFS].
>
> On Windows servers it can be
>   configured through the Autodisconnect registry key [KB297684]. 
>   \HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\ Value
>   type: Dword Value name: Autodisconnect Default:    15 (minutes)
>
> The Autodisconnect can also be configured through group policy:  Computer
>   Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local
>   Policies\Security Options “Microsoft network server: Amount of idle
>   time required before suspending session”

Maybe the update changed, or resetted, one of these parameters.

I suggest you to first try with the Group Policy and, if that fails, to directly edit the registry.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this at night when we have a slowdown.

Comment: *directly edit the register*...do you mean *registry*?

Comment: Yeah, the registry :)

Comment: @shodanshok In my case that policy was not defined, so it means it defaults to 15 minutes. I changed it to 1440 ( 24 hours) and will see what happens tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: > In my case that policy was not defined, so it means it defaults to 15 minutes. I changed it to 1440 ( 24 hours) and will see what happens tomorrow.  
> Actually, this might work.